# GNU Parallel: Giving a hint about execution time

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

**GIVEN**:

Some very much time-consuming jobs, `BIG0`, `BIG1`, etc. and a bunch of small fast jobs `fast0`, `fast1`, etc.

**QUESTION**:

Assume, that the `BIG*` jobs take **2 hours**, and the `fast*` jobs take **1 hour**. How can I instruct GNU Parallel to distribute the jobs over time and cores as follows

```
   time[h]    CPU[0]  CPU[1]     
     0        BIG0    BIG1     
     1         :        :       
     2        fast0   fast1
```

and not as shown below?

```
   time[h]   CPU[0]   CPU[1] 
     0       BIG0     fast0   
     1         :      fast1
     2       BIG1            
     3         :
```

The last setup would take one hour longer.

Comment: Sort your jobs by expected time, before submitting to `parallel` big ones first.

Comment: E.g. `parallel ... ::: BIG* fast*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach might be to sort your jobs by expected time, before submitting to **GNU Parallel**, big ones first:

```
parallel ... ::: BIG* fast*
```

Comment: I guess that means, that "there is no way to instruct GNU parallel to find a strategic decision about what job to run best at what time". Would you mind to explain your answer?

Comment: AFAIK that is correct... there is no way to instruct **GNU Parallel** to make strategic decisions about which order to run jobs in - it runs jobs in the order you give them and attempts to keep all CPU cores busy by starting the next job as soon as any other one finishes. Therefore, you should submit jobs in order of size, largest first, in a crude attempt at solving the "Bin Packing Problem". My suggested answer does that. If you want to try something more sophisticated, you can sort your jobs some other way and pass the list into **GNU Parallel** on `stdin`.